# Xmldocument: how to ask for the ID="1";

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have a xmlFile where 10 Levels are inside with diffrent attributes.

I try now to filter the Values with the ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Levels>>
    <Level ID="1">
        <Item.Count>
            20
        </Item.Count>
        <Size>
            <XS>7</XS>
            <YS>7</YS>
        </Size>
        <Rocks>
            <Position>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>1</Y>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>2</Y>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>4</Y>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>5</Y>
                <X>0</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
                <X>1</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>1</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
                <X>2</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>2</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
                <X>4</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>4</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
                <X>5</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>5</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>0</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>1</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>2</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>4</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>5</Y>
                <X>6</X>
                <Y>6</Y>
            </Position>
        </Rocks>
        <Colors>
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Color>White</Color>
            <Color>Yellow</Color>
            <Color>Green</Color>
        </Colors>
        <Probability>
            <isOneColoredFlower>30</isOneColoredFlower>
            <isTwoColoredFlower>50</isTwoColoredFlower>
            <isShovel>10</isShovel>
            <isButterfly>10</isButterfly>
        </Probability>
    </Level>
```

Is there any Method which i can use to filter for the Level ID, cause i have 10 IDS for 10 diffrent Values and need to use first just level 1 then level 2 etc..

thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to iterate through all levels or select only specific level with specified id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you using [xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256086(v=vs.100).aspx) and corresponding methods: [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx).

To get all Level nodes:

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Level");
```

You can iterate then through collection of Level nodes.

To get Level with specified ID:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Level[@ID='1']")
```

Comment: If you iterate through your collection, I guess something like this should work: `Console.WriteLine(level.Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value);`. Check [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) class for details.